What should I do if IntelliJ IDEA doesn't display images in javadoc?
I introduced the library "project reactor" in my application. Also, I downloaded the source code and Javadoc, but when I looked at its documentation, the image could not be displayed.


What should I do if IntelliJ IDEA doesn't display images in Javadoc?

This is a bug in IntelliJ Editor.
